# What does "As counter-intuitive as it may seem" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a sentence:

> As counter-intuitive as it may seem, some fruits and vegetables get a nutritional boost upon cooking.

I know the comparative idiom "as...as", but "As counter-intuitive as it may seem" still hard for me to understand. What is "it" here? Does it mean "some fruits and vegetables"? And if I want to rewrite this expression, how can i write it?

Comment: You should consider [waiting longer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"it" refers to common wisdom which would suggest fruits and vegetables lose nutritional value when cooked, so it is counter-intuitive that they would actually receive a boost.

You could rewrite the sentence:

*Some fruits and vegetables actually get a nutritional boost upon cooking.*

-or-

*Contrary to popular belief, some fruits and vegetables get a nutritional boost upon cooking.*

Answer (score 2):

The "it" in question is the entire following clause.

One way to paraphrase the sentiment is to lead with the independent clause.

> Some fruits and vegetables get a nutritional boost upon cooking, even though that may seem to be counter-intuitive.